# After applying CIFilter image got bigger no matter what I do

Tags: ios, swift, filter, resize

I read latest know-hows about applying CIFilter to UIImage and display it back. However I still get my image bigger than the original, don't know why. Maybe I'm missing some scaling factor?.

This is my screen with plain UIImageView and some image. The only constraints are center X/Y to superview.

Screenshot before applying filter

[image]

However I've added this code in `viewDidLoad()`:

```
let ciContext = CIContext(options: nil)
let coreImage = CIImage(image: ledImageView.image!)

let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIExposureAdjust")
filter!.setValue(coreImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
filter!.setValue(1.5, forKey: kCIInputEVKey)

let filteredImageData = filter?.outputImage as! CIImage
let filteredImageRef = ciContext.createCGImage(filteredImageData, from: filteredImageData.extent)

ledImageView.image = UIImage(cgImage: filteredImageRef!)
```

I get a result other than expected (yes, the filter is applied but size is broken). What did I do wrong?

Screenshot after applying filter

[image]

Answer (score 6):

I found both root cause of the issue and the solution. Apparently final UIImage was lacking of `scale` and `imageOrientation`. The original (source) image had **scale == 3.0** while image after processing stayed with **scale == 1.0**.

Here is the proper source code for this:

```
let ciContext = CIContext(options: nil)
let coreImage = CIImage(image: sourceImageView.image!)

let srcScale = sourceImageView.image.scale // <-- keep this value
let srcOrientation = sourceImageView.image.imageOrientation // <-- keep that value

let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIExposureAdjust")
filter!.setValue(coreImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
filter!.setValue(1.5, forKey: kCIInputEVKey)

let filteredImageData = filter?.outputImage as! CIImage
let filteredImageRef = ciContext.createCGImage(filteredImageData, from: filteredImageData.extent)

// use this constructor with scale/orientation values
ledImageView.image = UIImage(cgImage: filteredImageRef!, scale: srcScale: orientation: srcOrientation)
```

Now the result is as bellow :)

[Fixed image on ViewController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGCQd.png)

Answer (score 0):

Thats strange,

what are the values of the extends of the input and output image ? Do they match ?

You could try this

```
// crop the output image to the input's image extend
let croppedImage = filteredImageData.cropped(to: coreImage.extent)
let result = UIImage(ciImage: croppedImage)
```

Comment: Thanks for helping out! I printed _extent_ from _coreImage_ and _filteredImageData_ then I've the same output *(0.0, 0.0, 440.0, 393.0)*.

Comment: After that the cropping does not change anything since there's no need for cropping.

Comment: I think I have found the root-cause. I checked the *scale* of UIImages (original and created from CIImage). The original had scale 3.0 and final one has scale 1.0.  The property *scale* is read-only. How can I fix that?